# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText

Tags: java, android, kotlin

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
I am getting this exception lolipop and pre-lolipop android devices but on post lolipop devices it is working fine. My code is:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar"
                >

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/description"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                    android:lines="3"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: you should let you app theme extends from Theme.AppCompat (or its descendant) theme, like extends from Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.

Comment: https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Comment: Your code works perfect. check your theme.

Comment: Use this style `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>`

Comment: its already Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: thank you everyone for your comments problem is solved now

Comment: problem was i stored EditText background in only drawable v-24

Comment: @SarimAhmed Good to hear your issue is solved. To help others in the future, could you post it as an answer and self-accept it?

Comment: yeah sure problem was that there are only two directories in drawable in android studio 3.0 : drawable & drawable-v-24. I had a background xml file which i only added in drawable-v-24 i forgot to add in drawable too. That is why it was giving exception :)